# What kind of transmission fluid do I put in my 2012 Ford Escape?

Tags: ford, escape, atf

With some internet searches, is seems like the 2012 Ford Escape requires the `MERCON LV Automatic Transmission Fluid`, but I haven't found an official source to confirm that. Can anyone provide an official source that says that is or is not correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to page 325 of the [Owner's Manual](http://www.fordservicecontent.com/Ford_Content/catalog/owner_guides/12204og2e.pdf), it uses Mercon LV ATF or equivalent.

[image]

I know this to be true because I have an Escape also.

Comment: Perfect! Just the source I was looking for.

Comment: Also noticed that the dip stick has a label that says to use MERCON LV fluid